# java.net.SocketException: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 0: recv failed Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I run the load test in JMeter and i got this error.
Non HTTP response code: javax.net.ssl.SSLException/Non HTTP response message: java.net.SocketException: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 0: recv failed

why this kind of error i got??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can it be the case your system has both [IPv4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4) and [IPv6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6) enabled? If so you may run into situation when the request is being written in one thread and response comes in another hence it's "unrecognized"

So either choose one of network protocols in the operating system level and disable the other or limit JMeter to use only IPv4 by adding the next line to it's startup script:

```
jmeter -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -n -t test.jmx .....
```

if it helps you can make the change permanent by adding the next line to *system.properties* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation):

```
java.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

More information:

- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Overriding Properties Via The Command Line](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)